# Can't store data to a var (property) of a class

Tags: xcode, swift, properties

I know, my title is  confusing, but my problem is confusing for me, too. :-(

In the class ReadMoreTextView I've a var of the type NSAttributedString that I can fill but when I read it, it is **nil**!?
Ok, I've to declare this and that with my terrible English ;-)

I want to use a IMHO very nice solution "ReadMoreTextView" of **Ilya Puchka** to "compress" a large UITextView:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I want to use an `NSAttributedString`, because I want to "highlight" the "Read more" with a red or blue color.

For that I use this init:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var textView: ReadMoreTextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let text = "und ein neuer text Lorem ipsum dolor..."

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string:text as String)
    //                                                1)                   2)                         3)
    textView = ReadMoreTextView(maximumNumberOfLines: 3, attributedTrimText: attributedString, shouldTrim: true)
...
}
```

There

1. are the Number of the leading lines in the "compressed" view,
2. is the NSAttributedString and
3. is a Flag, if the Text should be trimmed

**And here is the class:**

```
class ReadMoreTextView: UITextView {
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        scrollEnabled = false
        editable = false
    }

    convenience init(maximumNumberOfLines: Int, attributedTrimText: NSAttributedString?, shouldTrim: Bool) {
       self.init()
        self.maximumNumberOfLines = maximumNumberOfLines  // 1)
        self.attributedTrimText = attributedTrimText      // 2)
        println(attributedTrimText)                       // of course displays the attributedTrimText
        self.shouldTrim = shouldTrim                      // 3)
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var maximumNumberOfLines: Int = 0 {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    var attributedTrimText: NSAttributedString? {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    var shouldTrim: Bool = false {
        didSet { setNeedsLayout() }
    }
```

Then I make a "po attributedTrimText" at a breakpoint at **shouldTrim** (last called), the result is **nil**?!

So because of the nil in attributedTrimText, the textView is empty when it will be displayed! :-(

I can't find the reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've set the class of the `textView` in the Storyboard to `ReadMoreTextView`, then the Storyboard instantiates the `ReadMoreTextView` class for you and assigns it to the `textView` `IBOutlet`.

On this line of code:

```
textView = ReadMoreTextView(maximumNumberOfLines: 3, attributedTrimText: attributedString, shouldTrim: true)
```

you are creating a new `ReadMoreTextView` and overwriting your outlet pointer `textView` pointing to this new `ReadMoreTextView`.  Unfortunately, now you are not interacting with the `ReadMoreTextView` that is on screen.

You shouldn't overwrite an `IBOutlet` variable.  You should just use it to read/write the properties of the `IBOutlet` variable.

```
textView.maximumNumberOfLines = 3
textView.attributedTrimText = attributedString
textView.shouldTrim = true
```

Comment: Urgh,, Me idiot :-(
Now everything looks like expected :-)
Ma any THX, vacawama!